# composer autoload.php failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, composer-php, shared-hosting

I am having problem with this error, I don't have Idea how to fix this.

> Warning: require_once(**DIR**/composer/autoload_real.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a2946484/public_html/vendor/autoload.php on line 5

what does it mean ?

Here is my autoload.php

```
// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitad1b46addec8855e522daae36df0556f::getLoader();
```

Comment: check your directory permissions

Comment: Blindshot: It also might be caused by older php version. Instead of `require_once __DIR__ . '/composer` try: `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/composer`.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest deleting the 'vendor' folder of your project and creating it again by running 'composer install' in your project folder in command line.